# Eclipse get stuck when developing Android apps

Tags: android, eclipse

My OS is Windows 7 and have 2 GB RAM , I use SDK 23.0.2 for Android development using Eclipse IDE. My machine get slow when I open Eclipse and I can't type and run programmes.  And also sometimes it show null pointer exception as well. Could you please help me, I am new to Android and can't understand ,
Whether this is a problem with version 23.0.2?
Lack of memory in my PC?
Can anyone give me reason to get slow? Also physical memory usage is 96% or so.
Are there any best practises I should follow?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PC is sort of "old" or anyways, the amount of RAM memory is really low.

I used to run eclipse on a core 2 duo (2.4GHz) proc. with 5GBs of ram and still had slight freezes.Not to mention that the Android Virtual devices were REALLY slow!

So, as long as you have a decent processor ,add some RAM memory to your PC/Laptop and you should be working just fine.

Good to know: An SSD would really speed up your computer too ,but focus on the RAM memory before anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but it work fine when I use SDK 22.X , but the problem is I need to use Google API , when upgrading I have to go to version 23.0.2. When I search to add Google API in 22.x there wan no where to check a box in SDK manager. Thanks a lot . I will increase my RAM.

Comment: To be honnest,I might have rushed in to an answer.Sorry for that. But anyways, increasing the ram cannot hurt anything else except your wallet.
I will do a bit of digging, perhaps there s some prboelsm with the SDK ,but I really doubt ,because I never had any sort of problem similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks.Is that ok, if I upgrade my RAM to 4/6GB? Do I need to use a real device instead of a Emulator. My CPU 2.3 GHz

Comment: Buy a cheap android device, second hand, I suggest minimum api level 16. Much more faster and has play services, so you don't have to waste time on genymotion.